# Design database for multi-category attribute

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have some products that belongs to the some category.

Each category can have different properties.

For example,

```
category cars has properties color, power, ...
category pets have properties weight, age, ...
```

Number of categories is about 10-15. Number of properties in each category is 3-15. Number of products is very big.

Main requirement for this app is very good search. We will select category, and enter criteria for each property in this category.

Have to design database for this scenario

Comment: When your data is searched, will a search look in any of the properties, like if you search for 24, will it match that as age and also as weight? Or will your searches always target a certain property for each value? Do you want to do calculations with property values, like calculate a birth year based on age, or body mass index on weight? Will you store the unit of measure for each of the properties (kg, year, cm, ...)?

Comment: If speed is of your concern, I'd probably go with columns storing different information and giving them their meaning on the application side based on the category. This is a bad design though. Normally, if you can have different set of attributes consider JSON datatype, EAV model (worse than JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you this model:

[image]

- Number of rows in categories is the number of categories
- Number of rows in products is the number of products
- You have a table for each property (here it is shown just weight) and the number of rows of each property table is the number of products with that property

This without consideration for the specific kind of main search you have to perform.

Regards

Comment: where  i can  store the value ?

Comment: The property table I designed is: idproperty, product_id, value. In this case I used weight.